# Add Salesforce CLI to Visual Studio on Macintosh

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

new to setting up VS code on a mac. I have the Salesforce CLI installed, but I can't find any resources that discuss how to add the Salesforce CLI to the terminal in VS code for the mac. On windows I just had to add the file path to settings.json.

Any help would be appreciated. [image: VS Code Terminal without SF CLI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your CLI installed you can access the CLI from any terminal.

You just have to enter a sfdx command through the terminal in VS Code.

For exemple, enter : sfdx force -h :)

[image]

Comment: I had determined that as well, but was looking for a drop down, but now that you mention it, I guess I don't really need it :)

Comment: Yep :) If my answer helped you, do not hesite to mark my answer  as the best one :p